# Hashing an unordered container without needing to implement a comparison operator for the type

Tags: c++, hash, boost-functional

I'm looking to hash an unordered container, such as an `unordered_map` and `unordered_set`.
For an ordered type, like a vector, `boost::hash_range(v.begin(). v.end())` works well, but it is also dependent on order, e.g.

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <functional>
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<std::vector<int>> {
        size_t operator ()(const std::vector<int>& v) const noexcept {
            return boost::hash_range(v.begin(), v.end());
        }
    };
}
```

Example of this working: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0544c1b146ebeaa0

[boost.org](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) says

> If you are calculating a hash value for data where the order of the
> data doesn't matter in comparisons (e.g. a set) you will have to
> ensure that the data is always supplied in the same order.

Okay, so that would seem easy - just sort the data in some way, but I don't want to do this every time I hash it. Using a normal `map` or `set` could work but I would need to do a fair bit of re-writing.

Additionally, this would require every type I use to have either `>`, `<`, `<=` or `>=` defined, as well as `==` and `std::hash`.

How can I hash a container so that the order does not matter?

Comment: You could try hashing the vector's elements, then sorting those hashes, then hashing the sorted set of hashes.

Comment: On a sidenote: You aren't allowed to create a specialization for `std::hash<std::vector<int>>`. Additionally, if you use a sorted container you'd only need to implement `operator<`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo What do you mean by the first point? I have a working example [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0544c1b146ebeaa0). For the second one, I've edited the post to clarify that only one is needed.

Comment: @Doot You don't have a program-defined type in the specialization, so placing it in `std` is not allowed. For the second part: You only need `operator<`. Defining one of the others doesn't help much. `operator<` is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement seems rather logical, since the hash function is combining the previous elements hash with the current element hash somehow, then the order is important, because

`H(A, B, C)` is then computed as `H(H(H(A), B), C)` so that each intermediate result is used as input to the next element (think about a block cipher).

To hash a sequence of elements without caring for ordering you'd need a commutative hash function, so you'd be restricted to commutative operations  (eg. XOR). I'm not sure how strong could be such an hash function but for your specific scenario it could be sufficient.

Comment: I don't think hash strength matters unless you expect a denial of service attack.  And even then a simple random salt added to the hash would probably prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After sorting the hash values of individual container elements, the sorted list of hash values can be hashed again to obtain a hash value for the unordered container.

Assume `H1` is the hash function for a single element and `H2` is the hash function for a list of hash values, then the hash value for some unordered container with elements A, B, and C could be calculated as `H2(SORT(H1(A), H1(B), H1(C)))`. By construction, the resulting hash value will be independent of the order. In this way, you will also get a stronger hash value compared to combining the individual hash values using commutative operations.